# Sending cloudwatch email from logs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using an EC2 instance. I have logged the exceptions in my applications to cloudwatch logs.
Format of log is a JSON object/string:

```
{
'application': 'abc',
'type': '404',
'error': 'The page you requested was not found.'
}
```

Now i want to email specific logs on an email address on the basis of log type for e.g: just the logs with type 404.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see SNS as a subscription to log group, but you can do this using Lambda function.

When the log match, trigger the lambda and from lambda, you can send an email or can perform any action based on the message.

Add filter on subscription.

```
aws logs put-subscription-filter --log-group-name /aws/ec2/execption --destination-arn arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456:function:send-email-on-exception --filter-name ec2-404-errors --filter-pattern "404"
```

**Filter and Pattern Syntax**

> You can use metric filters to search for and match terms, phrases, or
>   values in your log events. When a metric filter finds one of the
>   terms, phrases, or values in your log events, you can increment the
>   value of a CloudWatch metric. For example, you can create a metric
>   filter to search for and count the occurrence of the word ERROR in
>   your log events.

[FilterAndPatternSyntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html)

You can explore this [article](https://binx.io/blog/2018/11/19/lambda-cwlogs-subscription/) to read the aws CW log event.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for giving an idea about creating metrics to trigger certain events.